# Access to a database from a Spark job in synapse

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse, linked-service

I'm working within a *Synapse workspace*.

I have a *linked service* to a oracle database in a private network (10.x.x.x)

[image: Linked service]

I have a *SparkJob* which is trying to connect to that database with the oracle thin client and the default method in the spark library, i.e. *spark.read.jdbc*, and it can not reach it.

[image: Error message]

Is it possible for the spark job to reach the database?

I've tried to open firewall connections but can not find from where to where because the *Spark pool* is in a virtual network for which I don't know the network segment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read data from oracle DB using Pyspark inside synapse notebook
The Below steps will help you:

Step 1: Add the [jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/19.15.0.0.1/) ojdbc8-19.15.0.0.1.jar to the Synapse workspace packages.

Step 2: Add that [workspace package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-workspace-packages) to the Apache spark pool

Step 3:execute the following code:

```
host = 'my_host_url'  
port = 1521  
service_name = 'my_service_name'  
jdbcUrl = f'jdbc:oracle:thin:@{host}:{port}:{service_name}'  
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'  
    user = 'my_username'  
    password = 'my_password'  
    jdbcDriver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'  
    jdbcDF = spark.read.format('jdbc') \  
        .option('url', jdbcUrl) \  
        .option('query', sql) \  
        .option('user', user) \  
        .option('password', password) \  
        .option('driver', jdbcDriver) \  
        .load()  
    display(jdbcDF)
```

By following the above steps you can read data from oracle db in spark notebook.

Comment: Hi @Dileeprajnarayan,


I tried your solution but got the same error: 


`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3902.load.
: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection


 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out`



Do you think that I have be aware of any network rules?

Comment: @RicardoOlvera try allowing the network and IP address try the above process.
Also in the beginning of the code. use from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

and this spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/path/to/oracle-jdbc-driver.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

Comment: @RicardoOlvera check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQe6VYjS7UY&t=401s&ab_channel=WafaStudies